# Sliding TabBarController off screen when pushing new view on to navigationController

Tags: iphone, ios

In apple's "TheElements" example project, the tabBarController slides off screen with the rest of the view when pushing a view onto the tab button's navigation controller.

I cannot seem to see any code that specifically allows this??? But yet it happens..

Can someone point out what they are doing different?

From what I see:
Create navigationControllers
create views and push onto navigationControllers
create tabbar and push navigation controllers as the tabBar's view array.

This is the conventional way to setup tab controllers but I cannot replicate the tab bar sliding off screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can disable the TabBar when pushing controllers with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`:

```
[myController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
[navController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! This was in the pushed controller's init function and I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AtomicElementViewController.m, line 75:

```
  self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

If you set this to NO, the tab bar will NOT be hidden, and will thus remain visible.